# MySQL tables randomly dropped but .ibd files still exists

Tags: mysql, restore

I have a database server for a side project and one day between a period of the server being off - three tables been randomly been dropped. But the .ibd files for those tables still exist. There's nothing in the error logs neither.

What happened? The only users with drop permissions is the root user and the user for phpmyadmin. And the server is a LAN only server with no access from the outside internet.

Is it possible to restore the tables from the .ibd files? I haven't added any new tables or inserted new rows since this. I am running MySQl 8 so no .frm files are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what happened. For some reason the datadir reverted back to default setting despite it still being set in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`. I changed the datadir from default to a custom path when I had only one table. So when it reverted it appeared that all the tables I added since then were dropped.

To fix this I added

```
[mysqld]
datadir = /my/custom/path
```

to the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file.

I still don't know the cause of datadir reverting to default, perhaps maybe a mounting issue with the secondary drive upon boot?